# Unable to use androiddriver or iosdriver in Jbehave based serenity-bdd framework?

Tags: java, bdd, appium, jbehave, thucydides

I'm having trouble getting the android driver to work correctly in a jbehave based serenity-bdd project

I've created the project using the serenity-jbehave archtype and in the generated AcceptanceTestSuite class, I create a AndroidDriver with all of the relevent desired capabilities. (When the driver configuration is used in a Junit test, it works correctly so I am confident it is not a problem with any of the driver's configuration).

My problem is that once my stories start executing, the project appears to completely forget about this driver and instead use whatever driver has been set up as the default.

What am I missing? Should I be doing this configuration in the serenity.properties file? (I found that adding android as the webdriver.driver config option doesn't work).

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: Could you please post the code where you initialize your webdriver e.g. AcceptanceTestSuite class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The driver confguration used by the framework is held in the serenity.properties file associated with the project.